# Unable to use domain as AWS CloudFront distribution-S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, amazon-certificate-manager

Here is the process I followed so maybe I can have some help here:

1. I registered and paid for a domain on Amazon Route 53
2. I am trying to host a static website on a S3 bucket so I created a Hosted Zone with the apex domain (`example.com`) and an alias (`www.example.com`) pointing to the apex hosted zone and a record type `NS` and `SOA` were created by default.
3. Uploaded my webpage to S3. In properties I can access to this page trough a link `http://example.com.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com`, but this does not have SSL / TLS certificates, so the webpage is not accessible without warnings.
4. To be able to use CloudFront I intended to request public SSL / TLS certificate through the AWS Certificate Manager, for `example.com` and `www.example.com`
5. Now my distribution is active on CloudFront, but the domain is `someid.cloudfront.net`. I have tried a lot of things and read documentation but its confusing for me to use the domain from Route 53 to redirect it to the CloudFront domain. Any advice?

Tried to remake all the process again but I don't know what else I need to do. I'm expecting to use the domain I registered on Route 53 to redirect it to the CloudFront distribution.

Comment: Might help: [Using custom URLs by adding alternate domain names (CNAMEs) - Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use can just use Alternate domain in Cloudfront and add the url where you have to redirect it to, you can refer the below blogs

https://crishantha.medium.com/hosting-a-secure-aws-cloudfront-endpoint-via-aws-route-53-be65d42191b7

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html

Comment: The cloudfront dist works well, i can access by the cloudfront link, the thing is domain cant be reached directly, No response even that is registered on whois.com and routed the alias to the apex zone that points to the cloudfront dist, but somehow cant reach the domain, any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps to live your site hosted in Cloudfront (S3 as origin) through route53:

**Prerequisites**
Make sure you've added `example.com` and `www.example.com` as an alias in Cloudfront distribution origin.

To do so, follow the below steps:

- Open your distribution
- Click on `General` tab
- Under Settings column
- Click on edit
- Add your domain (`www.example.com`) as alias in `Alternate domain name` column, (you can add multiple domains here)
- Choose ACM certificate under `Custom SSL certificate` (If you don't have one you can request one in ACM, it's pretty easy, and you can get it in less than 5 min)

**ACM Certificate Generation Checklist**

- region should be `us-east-1`
- You should add all the other subdomains you need to include in this certificate, like `*.example.com` (to support [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) using `Add another name to this certificate`

**Route 53 Steps**

- Create Record
- Choose Record Type as `A`
- Check the `alias` option
- In the `Route traffic to` field, choose `Alias to Cloud front distribution`
- Choose the distribution (`someid.cloudfront.net`)
- Save and wait for it to be live.

This should work.

Comment: Ty for answering, i waited to make some testing, but now i think im close to the problem, i just registered another domain for another webpage, intended to use ACM on it for a certificate trough DSL validation, and now, some memories come to my head when i created the first one, i tried initially (on the first domain that i bought) to validate trough DSL validation, waited like 2 days and nothing happened, pending value stayed and used email validation, all cool with it process, and now, 3 days ago bought the new domain and tried to use DSL validation, and stilll pending.

Comment: i can see the example.com (my domain) domain on whois.com, but somehow i cant reach it because an DNS issue, i can access the cloudfront dist, but cant route my domain to it, could be 'cause something related to non DSL validated certs?

Comment: i got this message from browser when i try the page domain DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN